# Has anybody except Shahid Afridi hit 12 runs off one ball in cricket?

Tags: cricket, trivia

Shahid Afridi has hit 12 runs off one ball ([video link](https://youtu.be/xoLeoAjG4jI)).

Except him, has another batsman ever in cricketing history hit 12 runs off one ball?

Comment: All: please don't get into arguments about semantics. If it's clear what "double six" is *intended* to mean, then that's OK. We don't always have to use the precise rulebook terminology for everything (it's very rarely referred to as a "Boundary 4", and crossing sports nobody calls it "kicks from the penalty mark"). And as a general reminder to everyone, please try and keep within the spirit of the [Code of Conduct](https://sports.stackexchange.com/conduct). Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. Afridi is not the only player to do so, and arguably didn't deserve it, unlike

## Travis Birt

*January 2012: Big Bash League, for Hobart Hurricanes v Melbourne Stars*

Clint McKay took the fifth over bowling to Birt, beginning it with 0, 4, 4, 6.

His first attempt at the fifth ball was a no ball hit for Boundary Six (total: 6, 1 bye). His second attempt was a repeat of the first (total: 12 runs, 2 byes).

On the third delivery he finally kept his foot back, and Birt played it on for the wicket.